# C# - how to retrieve items you ave added using Attributes.Add?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox which I have added an attribute to using the following code:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("type", "textbox");
```

I have searched on the net but couldn't find any examples. How can I retrieve the value stored for the "type" key?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkeesb2c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the indexer: `TextBox1.Attributes["type"]`

Answer (score 1):

```
TextBox1.Attributes["type"]
```

[Control.Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have tried to index the Attributes by the type name like in the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes.aspx).  It looks like you should be able to access the collection like any other Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery. It is very handy:

```
var type = $("#texBoxId").attr("type");
```

Unless, server-side isn't the only way to go for you, of course

Answer (score 0):

You can simply Use

TextBox1.Attributes.Add("typ", "teestValue");

```
    foreach (String key in TextBox1.Attributes.Keys)
    {
        Response.Write(key + "=" + TextBox1.Attributes[key] + "<br />");
    }
```